# Search for placeholder in word document

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to search for specific placeholder and replace it with text in word template using Apache POI with Java, I want something simple not to loop on all tables, rows, cells, and runs to search for each text in it.

Comment: Could you add some example data and your code? PS: I think there is no easier solution than iterate thought cells.

EDIT: found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618763/find-excel-cell-by-text-in-apache-poi) which could help you

Comment: for (XWPFTable tbl : doc.getTables()) { 
    for (XWPFTableRow row : tbl.getRows()) {
 for (XWPFTableCell cell : row.getTableCells()) {
  for (XWPFParagraph p : cell.getParagraphs()) {
   for (XWPFRun r : p.getRuns()) {
  String text = r.getText(0);
  if (text != null && (text.equalsIgnoreCase("$comment"))) { 
                   //do something}
                 }}}}

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at my project https://github.com/centic9/poi-mail-merge which does something similar already.

It basically retrieves an XML-representation of the word document, does the replacement and puts the result back into the document.

I.e. something like

```
    CTBody body = doc.getDocument().getBody();

    XmlOptions optionsOuter = new XmlOptions();
    optionsOuter.setSaveOuter();

    // read the current full Body text
    String srcString = body.xmlText();

    ... do the replacements in srcString

    XmlOptions optionsOuter = new XmlOptions();
    optionsOuter.setSaveOuter();
    String srcString = src.xmlText();
    String prefix = srcString.substring(0,srcString.indexOf(">")+1);

    final String mainPart;
    // exclude template itself in first appending
    if(first) {
        mainPart = "";
    } else {
        mainPart = srcString.substring(srcString.indexOf(">")+1,srcString.lastIndexOf("<"));
    }

    String sufix = srcString.substring( srcString.lastIndexOf("<") );
    String addPart = append.substring(append.indexOf(">") + 1, append.lastIndexOf("<"));
    CTBody makeBody = CTBody.Factory.parse(prefix+mainPart+addPart+sufix);
    src.set(makeBody);
```

Note that the implementation is confused if the replacement is split across multiple formatings, e.g. if part of the replacement-tag is bold, this is inherent in the way that it works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was helpful but you have any technique to remove specific table (section) in the document has known $placeholder.