# Find a cell in excel base on column and row name - Java

Tags: java, excel

First of all sorry for this dumb question.

I have an excel file with the below values (check image).
i know how to read it in java if i will search by cell B1 or B2 or B4 ect.

There is a way to say in Java find the cell with row name Qurter 2 and column name Test 2 ?

[image]

Comment: This post might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618763/find-excel-cell-by-text-in-apache-poi . Apache POI can be used for reading Excel Sheets in a Java application.

Comment: Does it has to be excel file? In what format ???

Comment: Yes unfortunately, the format is .xls

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple. First get the rowindex using the row name and get the column index using the column name. Then read the excel file using row index and column index. 
Say you have found A3 as your Row name and C1 as your column name then you need to look C3 i.e the cell wihch you are looking for.
Hope this helps